# Burninate [manifest.xml]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The [manifest.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/manifest.xml) tag seems to be fairly useless. 24 tagged questions, 10 this year, no wiki.

Most of the questions with this tag are related to Android (some of which are also tagged [android-manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-manifest). The additional tag is redundant in these case.

However, it has some legitimate use in a few other cases - [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536779/c-builder-delphi-2010-application-manifest-template) - , but these questions ought to just be tagged [manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/manifest). This [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/manifest) is used much more and albeit not specific, has valid use in the cases where there is not a more specific tag available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went ahead and either retagged, edited or close voted those questions.

There are no remaining questions with that tag. The tag itself will be removed at 03:00 UTC when the clean-up script runs.